# Json to avro conversion

Tags: java, json, avro

I'm converting Json to avro. I have json data in  `JSONArray`. So while converting it into byte array i'm facing the problem.

below is my code:

```
static byte [] fromJsonToAvro(JSONArray json, String schemastr) throws Exception {

ExcelToJson ejj = new ExcelToJson();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


if (json != null) { 
    int len = json.length();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
        list.add(json.get(i).toString());
    } 
}


InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(list.getBytes()); //json.toString().getBytes()

 DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input); 
                  .
                  . 
                  .//rest of the logic
```

So how can i do it? How to convert JsonArray object to bytes(i.e., how to use getBytes() method for JsonArray objects). The above code giving an error at `list.getBytes()` and saying getBytes() is undifined for list.

Answer (score 10):

Avro works at the record level, bound to a schema.  I don't think there's such a concept as "convert this JSON fragment to bytes for an Avro field independent of any schema or record".

Assuming the array is part of a larger JSON record, if you're starting with a string of the record, you could do

```
public static byte[] jsonToAvro(String json, String schemaStr) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = null;
    DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> writer = null;
    Encoder encoder = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaStr);
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
        writer = new DataFileWriter<GenericRecord>(new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>());
        writer.create(schema, output);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
        GenericRecord datum;
        while (true) {
            try {
                datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                break;
            }
            writer.append(datum);
        }
        writer.flush();
        return output.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        try { input.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For an on-line json to avro converter check the following URL

http://avro4s-ui.landoop.com

It is using the library [avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s) that offers a lot of conversions including json=>avro

Comment: Is there any API for this ?

Comment: The converter does not seem to work anymore, it won't change its output when I'm changing the example.

Answer (score 4):

This discussion is likely useful:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-user/201209.mbox/%3CCALEq1Z8s1sfaAVB7YE2rpZ=v3q1V_h7Vm39h0HsOzxJ+qfQRSg@mail.gmail.com%3E

The gist is that there is a special Json schema and you can use JsonReader/Writer to get to and from that. The Json schema you should use is defined here:

https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/trunk/share/schemas/org/apache/avro/data/Json.avsc